# Selenium webdriver unable to find Mozilla geckodriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, firefox, rspec

gem selenium-webdriver 3.2.2

FF 51.0.1 (64-bit)

OS Ubuntu 16.04

I do not run tests, getting the error.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
    Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver.
```

I established geckodriver 1.14.0, but the error remained.

Comment: As the error message says, put the downloaded geckodriver somewhere in your path.

Answer (score 5):

Put this on your Gemfile

```
# Gemfile
gem 'geckodriver-helper'
```

And then in your spec_helper file

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox)
end
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed :)